# How To make existing data in sequence order in a table with sql Query

Tags: sql

I have a query for the below data I have inserted record in a table like below now I want to edit/alter table and make `MEMBER_ID` in sequence. Please suggest

```
MEMBER_ID   MEMBER_NAME     MEMBER_ADDRESS
-------------------------------------------    
1           Richa Sharma    Pune        
2           Garima Sen      Pune        
5           riya Sen        Latur       
4           WASEEM lAMBE    Pune        
3           Aziz sayyed     AURANGABAD
```

Comment: Leave it alone. IDs are not sequence numbers.

Comment: The only way to do it reliably is to add `ORDER BY` in your query that extracts the data.

Comment: "*Please suggest*" - do nothing. Just supply an `order by` when retrieving the data.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to alter the ids? This may lead to many problems such as breaking links to other tables. You may use `ORDER BY` to order them in any way you like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY MEMBER_ID
```